# OpenAPI Generator ignores a header definition with an underscore in the property name

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I have an OpenAPI 3.0.0 description with multiple headers marked `required: true` but one of the header definitions containing an underscore is being ignored by OpenAPI Generator.

Partial snippet...

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3000/myapi
paths:
  /place/{id}:
    get:
    x-eov-operation-id: find place
    x-eov-operation-handler: Ctrl
    parameters:
      - name: unique_id
        in: header
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        description: unique id
      - name: app-code
        in: header
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
        description: unique id
    responses: <<continued with response     definition>>
```

Header validation for `app-code` works as expected but `unique_id` validation is bypassed. As soon as I change `unique_id` to `unique-id`, it works fine.

Here is the snippet of middleware function which validates API specifications -

```
app.use(
 openapiValidator.middleware({
  apiSpec: yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(swaggerFilePath)),
  validateRequests: true,
  operationHandlers: path.join(_dirname + 
 '/api/controllers')
 })
)
```

Is an underscore forbidden in OpenAPI 3.0 specification?

Answer (score 0):

According to the OAS 3.0.x specification, your use of `_` is valid.

```json
"parameters": {
          "type": "object",
          "patternProperties": {
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+$": {
              "oneOf": [
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Reference"
                },
                {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Parameter"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
```

*src: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/schemas/v3.0/schema.json#L223C9-L236C12*

this may be an error with the package you are using. You didn't articulate where the header validation is "bypassed".

Comment: I have added the snippet of validation middleware. This is where the validation gets bypassed and reaches controllers.